# How to fix the grid of images in my CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a portfolio to showcase some of my past work and I want to showcase it in a 2 by 2 grid in the center. When doing so it creates several spaces and also has the background color of the image between the spaces. Here are my HTML and CSS portions of the code relating to the section. I am fairly new at these languages and thought it would be a good way to learn them by creating this. Please see the link to the picture to further understand my issue.

Here is the CSS and HTML portions:

```css
.my-work {
    background-color: var(--clr-dark);
    color: var(--clr-light);
    text-align: center;
    
}

.portfolio{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2[enter image description here][1], 1fr);
    margin-top: 5em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;   
    
}

.portfolio__item{
    background: var(--clr-accent);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio__img{
    transition: transform 750ms cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 0.5, 1),
    opacity 250ms linear;
}

.portfolio__item:focus{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.portfolio__img:hover,
.portfolio__item:focus .portfolio__img{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0.85;

}
```

```html
<!--My Work-->
        <section class="my-work" id="work">
            <h2 class="section__title">Projects</h2>
            
            <div class = "portfolio" >
                <a href = "a" class = "portfolio__item">
                    <img src = "img/port1.png" class="portfolio__img" >
                </a>

                <a href = "a" class = "portfolio__item">
                    <img src = "img/port2.jpg" class="portfolio__img" >
                </a>

                <a href = "a" class = "portfolio__item">
                    <img src = "img/port3.jpg" class="portfolio__img" >
                </a>

                <a href = "a" class = "portfolio__item">
                    <img src = "img/port4.jpg" class="portfolio__img" >
                </a>

            </div>

           
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/MattWindle/pen/perZRG

Maybe this code pen could help you.
The important code parts are

```
display:grid;
```

That helps to browser understand what are you doing and:

```
grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
grid-column-gap: 20px;
grid-row-gap: 20px;
```

This specify the relation between the columns and five you an idea about how to implement.

PD. you can search on codepen.io a lot of examples to learn more css/html/js.

Comment: Please use a [repro] instead of a codepen. Read [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) and [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Both guidelines also apply to any other external resources such as codepens.

Comment: Thank you so much I will definitely try using this.

Comment: Is it possible to turn this into a dynamic grid? where when the window collapses it creates a 1x4 grid instead?